# how to check is interface's two props length is same?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I want to be two array props's length must be same.

but I do not know how to write it.

as is my code is ...

```
// useFoo.ts
interface Props {
  initialMessage: string;
  messageList: string[];
  messageTimeList: number[];
}

function useFoo({ initialMessage, messageList, messageTimeList }: Props) {
  if (messageList.length === messageTimeList.length) {
    console.log('I want to must be same');
  }
}


// SomeComponent.tsx
function SomeComponent() {

  useFoo({ initialMessage: 'hello world', messageList: ['h', 'e', 'l'], messageTimeList: [1, 2] });
  // I want to be this situation call error
}
```

I want to using at react hook like this code.

How to check two props length in interface ?

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand, but if you want to "error" when the arrays are not the same length just do this in the hook:
```
if (messageList.length !== messageTimeList.length) {
  throw new Error('provided arrays must be of the same length!')
}
```
is that what you want to achieve?

Comment: @Roomy Thanks to comment! but I want to be checking in interface! not runtime throwing error

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N9yMVN) meet your needs? If so I can post an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @jcalz Thanks to comment! That's what I need!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you care about tracking array length in the type system, you probably want to use [tuple types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types), where the exact length and order of array elements is specified.  So a `string[]` can have any number of strings in any order, but a `["h", "e", "l"]` must have exactly three elements whose values are the string [literals](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#literal-types) `"h"`, `"e"`, and `"l"`, in that order.

Assuming you want to be able to support any length of `messageList`, then you can't really write out `Props` as a specific type; you'd need something like an infinite [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) like `{messageList: [], messageTimeList: []} | {messageList: [string], messageTimeList: [number]} | {messageList: [string, string], messagetimeList: [number, number]} | ...`.  Instead, you probably want `Props` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in `T`, the type of `messageList`, and then use [tuple mapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) to express that `messageTimeList` should be the same shape as `T` except that its elements should be `number` instead of `string`.  It looks like this:

```
interface Props<T extends string[]> {
    initialMessage: string;
    messageList: [...T];
    messageTimeList: [...{ [I in keyof T]: number }];
}
```

Note that I've wrapped both `messageList` and `messageTimeList` properties in `[... ]`; that's a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) and I'm only doing it here to give the compiler a hint that you'd like it to infer tuple types for `T` instead of plain array types.

Anyway, `Props<["h", "e", "l"]>` would allow only `["h", "e", "l"]` for `messageList`, but for `messageTimeList` it would allow `[number, number, number]`.  You don't want to have to write out `Props<["h", "e", "l"]>` manually, and luckily you don't have to... you can write `useFoo()` to also be generic in `T` and have the compiler infer `T` for you when you call it:

```
function useFoo<T extends string[]>(
    { initialMessage, messageList, messageTimeList }: Props<T>
) {
    if (messageList.length === messageTimeList.length) {
        console.log('I want to must be same');
    }
}
```

And let's test it out:

```
useFoo({
    initialMessage: 'hello world',
    messageList: ['h', 'e', 'l'],
    messageTimeList: [1, 2] // error!
    //~~~~~~~~~~~~~ <--
    // Source has 2 element(s) but target requires 3.
});

useFoo({
    initialMessage: "abc",
    messageList: ['a', 'b', 'c'],
    messageTimeList: [1, 2, 3]
}) // okay
```

Looks good!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgApQPYAcDOAeAFWQgA9IQATHZHMKUAcwG0BdAPmQG8BYAKGQHJQwMMDgAbALIQcOOAwgAuGnUYBuPoOQBbGXIUAZYLWVMAdBYIsN-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)